# Handbrake output directory to include Title folder

Tags: windows-7, file-management, video-conversion, handbrake

I am using [handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) to convert my DVD's to .MP4 and have set the default output path

```
Tools -> Options -> Output Files
```

In here there is Default Path: which I have pointing to my Movies folder and then there is Format: which is how the file is named. My issue is that my directory structure is

```
\Movies
    \Title
        Movie.mp4
```

I'm trying to figure out how to have handbrake create the new Title directory and place the file in there.

The only options for Default path are `{source_path}` or `{source_folder_name}`, which doesn't accomplish the task as my Movies folder is not in the source directory.

Under Format the options are `{source}, {title}, {chapters}, {date}`
I tried entering `{source}\{title}` thinking this would create the folder path and then insert the file, however instead the output is `D:\Movies\Movie Name\Movie Name\Movie Name\1.mp4`, `{source}\{source}` produces similar results but with the mp4 file being named correctly. I am not sure why it repeats itself so many times.

How can I automates this with handbrake?

**UPDATE**

I am using version 0.9.8 of handbrake on Windows 7

Comment: I have exactly the same problem as you - I ended up getting the Handbrake UI to crash because it kept adding multiple copies of the "source" tag until the filename was too long for Windows' directory structure rules.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but I wanted my converted files to be placed in a new folder named MP4 so I used the path {source_path}\MP4\

This automatically creates an MP4 folder in the source directory of the original file. I hope this helps!